# Visual Studio 2012 and 2017 behavior for same website

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I have a website when I open that website in Visual Studio 2012, it does not create any solution file but Visual Studio 2017 creates a solution file while opening the same website. why?

See below -

In 2012 -

[image]

In 2017 -

[image]

I don't want to create a solution file.

Comment: VS *always* creates a solution when you open a project.  Hopefully the one that was used before, but if it can't find one then it will make one on-the-fly.  Intentionally hiding the solution node does not change what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for avoiding the solution file. Now Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2012 both looks same. I had "Always show solution" checked under Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General. I unchecked it.

See below - 
[image]

Now there is no solution file in VS 2017 -

[image]